# Multiple TabNavigators react native

Tags: react-native, tabnavigator

I am creating an app with two TabNavigators one at the top and one at the bottom.. but When I do that, the selected tab view is not taking the full screen rather than the screen is getting divided horizontally. where the bottom screen corresponds to the bottom TabNavigator and the top screen relates to the top TabNavigator.. is there a way around this in react native?

Comment: You haven't given much information or even a code snippet to help other to help you but I would guess that the may be because you have two view with {flex:1} fighting for the space, rather than being nested inside each other?

Comment: @MossPalmer thank you for your reply.. the code was something like: tabnavigatortop and Tabnavigatorbottom with items in them.. the problem was not only in the flex but also because they were two tabmavigators present at all times, which couldn't be done. The solution was to nest one of these tabmavigators into one of the other tabnavigator's items..